# Grepping only source code from PHP file

Tags: php, grep

Is there any clean grep one-liner to grep *only the PHP source* (the code between `<?` and `?>`) from a PHP file? Thus far I've tried:

```
grep -oiE "<\?php[[:print:]]*\?>" name_of_php_file
```

But it seems to return muddled entries like:

```
<?php print $row[0];?>"><img src="gallerybig/<?php echo $row[1];?>
```

Expecting a one-liner which would return **only** PHP source, without any muddled entries. sed and awk are OK.

---

**EDIT:** The expected output is PHP source code, even if it spans multiple lines. The sample output is bad, as it contains HTML in between: `"><img src="gallerybig/`

---

**EDIT 2:** The answer given by @SigmaPiEpsilon works, but grep doesn't print code that spans multiple lines. For example, this snippet of code doesn't show up in the output:

```
<?php 
$str="select c_id,c_description,cate_name,date from book_table ;";
$res=mysql_query($str); ?>
```

Comment: could you add 3-5 sample lines and explicitly show output needed? are the entries spread across lines? do you need to match only whole lines? etc... not sure why exactly the line shown should not be part of output (I don't know about php)

Comment: See my recent edits that works for multilines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use a non-greedy search by adding a `?` after the `[[:print:]]*`. This is not available in normal grep but available with Perl syntax by specifying `-P` flag instead of `-E`. Check `man grep` to make sure your grep supports this.

```
$ Var='<?php print $row[0];?>"><img src="gallerybig/<?php echo $row[1];?>'
$ echo $Var | grep -oiP "<\?php[[:print:]]*?\?>"
<?php print $row[0];?>
<?php echo $row[1];?>
```

To match this over multiple lines you have to specify a newline character and use the `-z` flag. The regex gets a little tricky, but instead of specifying non-greedy match with `?` you can use the complement match as `[^?]` which matches everything except `?`. See below

```
$ cat test_php 
<?php 
$str="select c_id,c_description,cate_name,date from book_table ;";
$res=mysql_query($str); ?>
<?php print $row[0];?>"><img src="gallerybig/<?php echo $row[1];?>
$ grep -oizP "<\?php[^?]*\n*\?>" test_php
<?php 
$str="select c_id,c_description,cate_name,date from book_table ;";
$res=mysql_query($str); ?>
<?php print $row[0];?>
<?php echo $row[1];?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do what you've described so far with GNU awk:

```
$ gawk -v RS='?>' 'RT{sub(/.*<\?/,"<?"); print $0 RT}' file
<?php
$str="select c_id,c_description,cate_name,date from book_table ;";
$res=mysql_query($str); ?>
```

but it's obviously not robust since that wouldn't account for `?>` inside a comment or inside string or inside HTML or... so whether or not it'll do what you want depends on the non-trivial cases that you haven't shown us yet IF they exist in your real input.